# How can i change name of a btn after login in react?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, web

Hi i am working on my new website..
I want to change the name of the Button shown below forms sign in to profile
and on-click i want to show a side bar about that profile in react.

Note: This sign in button is on my NavBar.

```
    <NavBtn>
        <NavBtnLink to="/login">Sign In</NavBtnLink>
    </NavBtn>
```

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Please take the [tour] (you get a badge!) and read through the [help], in particular [*How do I ask a good question?*](/help/how-to-ask) Your best bet here is to do your research, [search](/help/searching) for related topics on SO, and give it a go. ***If*** you get stuck and can't get unstuck after doing more research and searching, post a [mcve] of your attempt and say specifically where you're stuck. People will be glad to help.

Comment: Pass the button name dynamically, or handle it via ```prop``` or ```state```

Comment: u ca use const[toggle, isToggled] = useState(false)
and then us { toggle ? Sign in : 'your string'}  for example. But sorry, i haven't get for 100% what do you want ))

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In this case I'd conditionally render 2 separate buttons:

```
{!signedIn && <NavBtn>
    <NavBtnLink to="/login">Sign In</NavBtnLink>
</NavBtn>}
{signedIn && <NavBtn>
    <button onClick={handleClick}>Other button title</button>
</NavBtn>}
```

I know you can use conditional rendering on the same button and decide which string to display and which onClick handler to honor, but I find this cleaner to read and easier to test because now each button encapsulates its own properties and functionality.

You can decide how to determine the `signedIn` state, either by holding it in global state or something else that suites your needs.

Also not entirely sure what properties your components are designed to take, for example if `NavBtn` can take an `onClick` handler, if it does, you can pass the `onClick` there instead of nesting another button

Answer (score 1):

You can use

```
isUserLoggedIn ? <NavBtnLink onClick={showProfile}>View Profile</NavBtnLink> : <NavBtnLink to="/login">Sign In</NavBtnLink>
```